# Typesafe Config Environment Variables

Tags: configuration, playframework, akka, typesafe

Attempting to use `${HOSTNAME}` in a config file does not work! According to the documentation, config files should resolve environment variables as mentioned in the docs:

> substitutions fall back to environment variables if they don't resolve in the config itself, so ${HOME} would work as you expect. Also, most configs have system properties merged in so you could use ${user.home}.

**Is there a way to get hostname into the config file?**

**Reproduction**
Add `host.name=${HOSTNAME}` to an `application.conf` file, then try and access it from anywhere. For example try adding

```
Logger.info(s"Hostname is ${current.configuration.getString("host.name").getOrElse("NOT-FOUND")}")
```

to the `Global.scala`.

**Environment**
This was run on a RHEL6 environment where `echo $HOSTNAME` produces `precise32` so the environment variable exists, this is not the program `hostname`.

Comment: Did you set HOSTNAME explicitly as environment variable? "hostname" itself is a program. On which platform do you operate? How looks your application.conf and how do you retrieve the configuration setting?

Comment: Yes, please show us your `application.conf` and also where you use that in the application as well.

Comment: Updated question. HOSTNAME is set on the server, nothing special in application.conf besides attempting to set the `host.name` configuration variable.

Comment: FWIW I just came across this same annoying discrepancy between the docs and the actual implementation. If I remember correctly this same bug was there a few years back too. Maybe the Typesafe guys has abandoned the Typesafe Config project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution seems to be passing in the hostname via a system property as `-Dhost.name=$HOSTNAME` or `-Dhost.name=$(hostname)`. I'd imagine in windows it would be something else, but this works for *NIX environments.

Unless anyone can come up with something cleaner this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: What's happening here is that HOSTNAME is a shell variable but not an environment variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/differnce-between-the-shell-and-environment-variable-in-bash Another way to put it is that HOSTNAME is not "exported" it's just internal to the bash process. In lowlevel terms, when bash forks a child process it doesn't pass unexported variables to the child's environment. The practical implication is that you could solve this by doing `export HOSTNAME` before you start the JVM.

Answer (score 7):

This probably isn't working because `$HOSTNAME` doesn't seem to actually be an environment variable:

```
jamesw@T430s:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
T430s
jamesw@T430s:~$ export|grep HOSTNAME
jamesw@T430s:~$
```

So it must be some other special bash thing.

Comment: If the app is invoked via the shell then this variable should be available

Comment: I stand corrected: `scala> System.getenv("HOSTNAME")` and `scala> System.getProperty("HOSTNAME")` both return null.

Answer (score 1):

You should see if calling `System.getenv("HOSTNAME")` returns a non-null value.  If not, then `HOSTNAME` is not an env variable according to the java runtime which is what is important for mapping that to a config property in typesafe config.  I tried this with `HOSTNAME` and even though I could echo it in bash, it was not available in java as a env substitution.  I changed it to `USER` and everything worked as expected.

Comment: You're also correct, the test verified that HOSTNAME appears to be unavailable in the JVM as an environment variable. Thank you