# getenv Not Working for COLUMNS and LINES

Tags: c, environment-variables, getenv

I am trying to get the number of columns and lines in my program. I am using the following code to do so:

```
...

char *cols = getenv("COLUMNS");
printf("cols: %s\n", cols);

char *lines = getenv("LINES");
printf("lines: %s\n", lines);

...
```

The problem is that when I run this I get null for both. Running this with other environment variables, such as `PATH` or `USER`, works fine.

What I find strange is that running `echo $COLUMNS` and `echo $LINES` from the same shell both work fine.

Why is my program unable to get these two environment variables.

Comment: Did you try adding the definitions to `/etc/environment`?

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are automatically set by shell (at least by bash).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COLUMNS` and `LINES` are *set* by the shell, but not *exported*, which means that
they are not added to the environment of subsequently executed commands.
(To verify that, examine the output of `/usr/bin/env`: it will show `PATH` and `USER`, but not `COLUMNS` and `LINES`.)

In the bash shell, you can call `export VAR` to mark a variable for export.

Alternatively, see [Getting terminal width in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022957/getting-terminal-width-in-c)
for various ways to obtain the terminal width and height programmatically.

Comment: I was trying the suggestion from the first answer `getenv()` as it appeared simpler. The second method worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS`, they are probably not set. The xterm manual page states they *may* be set, depending on system configuration.

If you want to see what environment variables are passed to your program, use this little program (which uses the third, nonstandard "hidden" parameter to `main()` which should be available on all IXish systems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    while (*envp)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *envp++);
    }   
}
```

If you want a portable way to obtain your terminal window size, its probably best to use `ioctl(..., TIOCGWINSZ, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are shell variable, but not environment variables.

You could use `env` to show the list of environment variables in current shell, and `set` to show the list of shell variables. And you will find that environment variables are a subset of shell variables.

The answers to this question is helpful:
[differnce between the shell and environment variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/differnce-between-the-shell-and-environment-variable-in-bash)