# Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-sync

Im using [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem to upload assets to Amazon S3 bucket. I used [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to store my keys and secret keys and deployed using capistrano to Amazon EC2. Everything was fine.

But when I moved the keys to `.bash_profile` on my server and added an [initializer](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#custom-rails-initializer-configinitializersasset_syncrb), asset upload failed with this error.

```
rake aborted!
Fog directory can't be blank, Aws access key can't be blank, Aws secret access key can't be blank
```

Please help me to figure out why the keys/secrets are not found.

Comment: i would export the ENV variables, export FOG_DIRECTORY=name etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Basically means you've not set the ENV vars for your shell session. I guarantee if you run `rake assets:precompile FOG_DIRECTORY=[your_dir] AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[your_access_key] AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[secret_access]` you'll be able to perform the operation

> The best recommendation I can give right now is to look in the
>   `/etc/environment` file on your VM. If you have this file, you'll be
>   able to set the system-wide variables which *will* get used each time
>   you load your app

The problem is an issue between the assigning of [ENVIRONMENT & SHELL variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/differnce-between-the-shell-and-environment-variable-in-bash) - SHELL vars are only available in a specific shell session, whilst ENVIRONMENT vars are available throughout the system

I have not found how to declare shell-specific variables on the fly yet, by putting all the env vars inside `/etc/environment` it works for us

Comment: Hi Rich thanks for your answer, But the error occurs while deployment and capistrano does precompiling. Apart from these 3, I have many other variables set and all works fine. I will try ENVIRONMENT variable instead of a shell variable.

Comment: Yep it's the same issue we have - Capistrano doesn't have access to your SHELL vars. It's SSHing into your server & performing the action... hence why the vars aren't available

Comment: Hey, setting the vars in `/etc/environment` didn't work either

Comment: How strange! Can you try logging into the server with SSH & then performing the `rake assets:precompile` task with the SHELL vars like I posted above? If that works, it's a problem with your environment, else its an issue with your rails app