# why the new environment variable did not see by rust

Tags: shell, rust

I added a new environment variable into `~/.zshrc` in macOS 13.2 few minites ago, this is the content about the variable in `.zshrc`:

```
export ALT_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123456@reddwarf-postgresql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local:5432/alt
```

then run the source command to make it works:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

check the variable:

```
> env|grep "DATABASE_URL"
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123456@127.0.0.1:5432/dolphin
CV_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123456@reddwarf-postgresql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local:5432/cv
ALT_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123456@reddwarf-postgresql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local:5432/alt
```

when I using this rust code to read the environment variable in visual studio code with lldb plugin:

```
fn main() {
    let cv = std::env::var("CV_DATABASE_URL").expect("get cv url error");
    print!("cv:{}", cv);
    let alt = std::env::var("ALT_DATABASE_URL").expect("get alt url error");
    print!("alt:{}", alt);
}
```

the newly add variable read failed:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'get alt url error: NotPresent', src/main.rs:4:49
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
cv:postgres://postgres:123456@reddwarf-postgresql.reddwarf-storage.svc.cluster.local:5432/cv%
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have do some investgate seems the visual studio code lldb plugin could not read the os environment variable.

Comment: Weird that it finds `CV_DATABASE_URL` but not `ALT_DATABASE_URL`. Were the `env|grep` and the `cargo run` command executed in the same terminal session?

Comment: How and where are `DATABASE_URL` and `CV_DATABASE_URL` defined?

Comment: defined in the .zshrc using the export command

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same shell session for both `env` and your Rust code?

Comment: yes, I am sure the rust and shell env command are in the same shell session.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce: you have to use `export` for `source ~/.zshrc` to set them in your current shell, but either way Rust's `std::env::vars()` was always consistent with `env`.

Comment: I have do some investgate, in the terminal run the rust app, it works fine, but when I debbuging in visual studio code using lldb plugin, it could not read the environment variable. @kmdreko

Comment: It's not an **environment** variable unless you export it. Just `var=value` creates a _shell_ variable, not an _environment_ variable.

Comment: I have already exported it in the .zshrc using export command.

Comment: You might add that to the `.zshrc` fragment in the question, then.

Comment: That said, how are you starting VS Code? If you don't start it as a subprocess of a shell, it won't inherit variables the shell's startup creates.

Comment: (Also, which operating system are you on? How environment variables are set in interactive sessions is different between them; for that matter, it's different between traditional UNIX systems -- which typically had the GUI started by a login shell -- and more modern ones, which often don't).

Comment: I am using the macOS 13.2, seem I have to start the visual studio code from terminal to make it inherit the shell environment

Comment: There are other approaches as well; you can set environment variables direct in VS Code, or you can set them through launchd configuration.

Comment: I see you've edited the question to include the `export` in `.zshrc`. If it's really there then you should not need a further export, but in the original question the variable was only defined in `.zshrc`, so it's a shell variable and only visible to the shell itself. It's only visible to child processes when exported, as I explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to manage the rust environment varialbe, on the visual studio code `launch.json`, add the envFile configuration:

```
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

then in the project folder add an `.env` file and add the environment key value into `.env` like this:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
```

also you can choose the [dotenv](https://github.com/dotenv-rs/dotenv) package but I found this repo stop maintain for 3 years, not recommend.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a shell question than a Rust question, but the variable must be exported to be seen in child processes.

So run

```bash
export ALT_DATABASE_URL
```

before running your program.

You can also set and export at the same time:

```bash
export ALT_DATABASE_URL=whatever
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/difference-between-shell-and-environment-variables) for more details on non-exported (shell) and exported (environment) variables, personally I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348101/11831707) the best one.

Comment: If this is the cause, then why does it show up in `env|grep "DATABASE_URL"`?

Comment: can you explain the reason more detail? why should I do like that. why need to reexport the environment variable before read it in rust?

Comment: If this is the issue, the question should arguably be marked as a duplicate of [Difference between shell and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341372/difference-between-shell-and-environment-variables)